# Longest path in a tree with $n$ vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

> Let $T$ be a tree with $n$ vertices and with a vertex of degree $k$. Prove that the longest path in $T$ has at most $n - k + 1$ edges.

I'm unsure of how best to prove this. I know a tree has $n-1$ edges. Would I look at the vertex of minimum degree in order to maximise $n-k+1$? I feel like I'm missing something completely obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $v$ be the vertex of $T$ with degree $k$.  How many of the edges incident on $v$ *cannot* be involved in the longest path if $v$ is included in that longest path?  How many of those edges cannot be involved if $v$ is *not* included?

Account for the fact that $T$ has (as you say) $n-1$ edges in all, and conclude that...